# Display most voted posts

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using [ThumbsUp V2 Voting Script](http://www.geertdedeckere.be/shop/thumbsup/help) and i'm trying to display the posts based on the number of votes:

```
<?php $items = ThumbsUp::items()->orderby('votes_total')->get() ?>
```

The values are stored in mysql so i thought of:

```
$display = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banat");
$items = ThumbsUp::items($display)->orderby('votes_total')->get() ;
```

But i thik i've definitely done this wrong since it's just displaying an output:

```
Array
```

Comment: `mysql_query()` returns a resource, not an array or string.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an array, you must loop on it to show the data. You cannot just do an `echo` on a var that is an array. You should have something like this:

```
foreach($items as $item)
{
   echo $item;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$items` is an array, and I assumed you attempted to

```
echo $items;
```

Instead you will need to loop over it:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {

  // View the structure of `$item`
  print_r($item);
}
```

If you only expect `$items` to hold one thing, then just do:

```
print_r($items[0]);
```